# Will I be interrogated if I bring $9000 to the US

Tags: customs-and-immigration

Is there any chance the cash will be seized even if it is less than 10k USD?

Comment: The chance always exists. Civil forfeiture does not only happen for values over 10k; they just need to be "suspicious".

Comment: Why do you need to bring so much cash? There are many safer ways of moving money around the world.

Comment: because of the conversion rates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$9000 is below the limit for declaration ($10,000) so you don't have to declare it, and it's legal to bring it into the country.

It is, however, a large amount of money. If you're stopped for some reason and it is discovered it is close enough to the declaration limit to be suspicious. If you have good documentary evidence that the money is yours and that you came by it by legal means then you *should* be OK, but that won't stop an over-zealous officer seizing it for further investigation.

If you can, use a bank to transfer the money.